# Android ListView: Changes made to Items affect other Items

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter

I know that this is a very common problem faced when using ListView. However, I couldn't find anything wrong with my implementation as I have properly followed the ViewHolder Pattern for my Custom Adapter.

**The Problem:**

Changes made to an item, such as changing the textview's text in one time affects other random items when scrolled down/up. When I scroll back up, the original item is changed as well as other items.

This issue can be fixed with a **ViewHolder** pattern.  It's weird cos I still get the problem!

**Adapter code:**

```
public class TrackerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    ArrayList <Set> sets = new ArrayList <> ();

    public TrackerAdapter(Activity a, final ArrayList <Set> sets) {
        this.activity = a;
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.sets = sets;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return sets.size();
    }
    public Set getItem(int position) {
        return sets.get(position);
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        final Set set = sets.get(position);
        final Holder holder;
        try {
            if (view == null) {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_single, null);
                holder = new Holder();
                holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
                view.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (Holder) view.getTag();
            }
            holder.name.setText(set.getUser().getName());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("CHECK", "Error at TrackerAdapter");
            Log.d("CHECK", Log.getStackTraceString(ex));
        }
        return view;
    }
    public static class Holder {
        TextView name;
    }
}
```

What issue do you see in my code? Have I implemented the ViewHolder pattern properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks correct so I'm gonna take a wild guess and say that you modified the backing `ArrayList` from outside. You can't do that without notifying the `ListView` after making a change.

The following code will decouple your working array and the data that is showing.

```
final ArrayList <Set> sets = new ArrayList <> ();

public TrackerAdapter() {
}

public void setItems(ArrayList<Set> sets) {
    this.sets.clear();
    this.sets.addAll(sets)
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    final Set set = sets.get(position);
    final Holder holder;

    if (view == null) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_single, parent, false);
        holder = new Holder();
        holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (Holder) view.getTag();
    }

    holder.name.setText(set.getUser().getName());

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :) I am a bit confused though. What is setItems and when is it called? Also, why have you emptied out the constructor?

Comment: **1)** Call `setItems` whenever you make changes to the data set. That includes adding items, removing items, modifying items, moving items around. **2)** The constructor is empty because I don't need anything there. I obtain a `LayoutInflater` when I need it from the `ListView` (parent) which should avoid any theme related issues (imagine activity had a different theme than the list view).

Answer (score 0):

**By using Array Adapter**

```
Holder holder = new Holder();
if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_single, null);
    holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
}
holder.set = getItem(position);
holder.name.setText(holder.set.getUser().getName());
public static class Holder {
    TextView name;
    Set set;
}
```

**By using Base Adapter**

```
Holder holder = new Holder();
if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_single, null);
    holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
}
holder.name.setText(sets.get(position).getName());
public static class Holder {
    TextView name;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you changed here?

Comment: yes sure.. i removed the final keyword and get value in the arraylist with the help position

Comment: I use the BaseAdapter but no luck mate. Still get the issue

Comment: can you share me set class ?

Comment: It's just String Name with a getter setter in that class

Comment: Ok fine you can set the values  in this way 
holder.name.setText(holder.get(position).getName());

Comment: oh sorry not holder your list, sets.get(postion).getName());

Comment: Isn't it the same thing as 'final Set set = sets.get(position);' and then setting the name as ''holder.name.setText(set.getUser().getName());". Basically whats in the question? How is it different mate?

Answer (score 0):

What's the way you change your TextView's text? Right in TextView itself or in the corresponding item of ArrayList, and then just adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()?

And a strange thing. getViewTypeCount() returns the number of XMLs you suppose to inflate in the list. if you have only 1 xml, return 1 is okay (but, as for me, when it's 1, explicitly write this method is redundant). But in getItemViewType() you should write conditions depending on which an item gets one or another viewType. And you return the current position, better fix it :)

Comment: I change the textview in the line: ' holder.name.setText(set.getUser().getName());' inside the adapter